# improving an Sprintf for a micro

Tags: c, microcontroller, msp430

I'm currently writing some code to runing using a small micro controller, and need to implement a version of Sprintf (the standard library version is too large). I have managed to create a version however I was wondering what people though of it and if anyone might be able to suggest any improvements, specifically any suggestions to get it to run a little faster, or to decrease the code size.

The function as it currently stands is:

```
int sprintf(char *s, const char *format, ...){
    char c;
    char i;
    long n;
    char length;
    char *string;
    va_list a;
    va_start(a, format);


    while (c = *format++) {                                     //keep going untill the whole string is written to the array, increasing the pointer each loop round

        if (c == '%') {                                         //is the next character special 
            switch (c = *format++) {                            // move to the next postition to see what to do
                case 's':                                       // read a String from the corresponding variable
                    string = va_arg(a, char*);
                    i = 0;
                    while (string[i] != NULL) {
                        *s++ = string[i];
                        i++;
                    }

                    break;
                case 'i':                                       // read an integer from the corresponding variable
                    n = va_arg(a, int);
                    if (n > 100000) {
                        *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 100000 % 10);
                    }
                    if (n > 10000) {
                        *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 10000 % 10);
                    }
                    //Deliberately no break, rolls through to case below
                case 'c':                                       // read a char from the corresponding variable
                    if (c == 'c') {
                        n = va_arg(a, char);
                    }
                    if (n > 100) {
                        *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 100 % 10);
                    }
                    if (n > 10) {
                        *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 10 % 10);
                    }
                    *s++ = IntToAcii(n % 10);
                    break;
                case '0':                                       // inserts the number from the variable with padded 0 if it is too small to have a set size
                    length = *format++;
                    length -= 0x30;
                    switch (c = *format++) {
                        case 'i':                               // read an int from the corresponding variable (with padding)
                            n = va_arg(a, int);
                            if (length > 6) {
                                length = 6;
                            }
                            if (n > 100000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 100000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 6) {
                                *s++ = '0';
                            }
                            if (n > 10000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 10000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 5) {
                                *s++ = '0';
                            }
                            if (n > 1000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 1000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 4) {
                                *s++ = '0';
                            }
                            //Deliberately no break, rolls through to case below
                        case 'c':                               // read a char from the corresponding variable (with padding)
                            if (c == 'c') {
                                if (length > 3) {
                                    length = 3;
                                }
                                n = va_arg(a, char);
                            }
                            if (n > 100) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 100 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 3) {
                                *s++ = '0';
                            }
                            if (n > 10) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 10 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 2) {
                                *s++ = '0';
                            }
                            *s++ = IntToAcii(n % 10);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'p':                                                   // inserts the number from the variable with padded spaces if it is too small to have a set size
                    length = *format++;
                    length -= 0x30;
                    switch (c = *format++) {
                        case 'l':                                           // read a long from the corresponding variable (with padding)
                            if (length > 9) {
                                length = 9;
                            }
                            n = va_arg(a, unsigned long);
                            if (n > 100000000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 100000000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 9) {
                                *s++ = ' ';
                            }
                            if (n > 10000000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 10000000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 8) {
                                *s++ = ' ';
                            }
                            if (n > 1000000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 1000000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 7) {
                                *s++ = ' ';
                            }
                            //Deliberately no break, rolls through to case below
                        case 'i':                                       // read an int from the corresponding variable (with padding)
                            if (c == 'i') {
                                if (length > 6) {
                                    length = 6;
                                }
                                n = va_arg(a, int);
                            }
                            if (n > 100000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 100000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 6) {
                                *s++ = ' ';
                            }
                            if (n > 10000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 10000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 5) {
                                *s++ = ' ';
                            }
                            if (n > 1000) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 1000 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 4) {
                                *s++ = ' ';
                            }
                            //Deliberately no break, rolls through to case below
                        case 'c':                                       // read a char from the corresponding variable (with padding)
                            if (c == 'c') {
                                if (length > 3) {
                                    length = 3;
                                }
                                n = va_arg(a, char);
                            }
                            if (n > 100) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 100 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 3) {
                                *s++ = ' ';
                            }
                            if (n > 10) {
                                *s++ = IntToAcii(n / 10 % 10);
                            } else if (length >= 2) {
                                *s++ = ' ';
                            }
                            *s++ = IntToAcii(n % 10);
                            break;
                    }
            }

        } else {
            *s++ = c;                                           //save the character from the string
        }
    }
     return(1);
}
```

Comment: `%c` should put in a single character, not a number.

Comment: `while(string[i] != NULL)` in the `%s` handler is confused; it should be `while(string[i] != '\0')`.

Comment: @StilesCrisis I did it that way because for my use there is no need for a single character to be written at any point, but I do need to be able to send different sized (8,16,32 bit) numbers.

Comment: Well you asked for people to critique an "sprintf replacement." I would suggest if you are going to modify the base behaviors, use your own letters instead of repurposing existing ones.

Comment: 1) `if (c == 'c') { n = va_arg(a, char); }` should be `unsigned char uc = (unsigned char) va_arg(a, int);`. 2) There are _dozens_ of issues with this code.  Suggest posting a much smaller example, say only printing `%d` and `%s`, and _then_ work up from there.

Comment: You should post this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You will have problems with a trailing `%`. I believe you would end up reading past the trailing null character. I'd suggest that you convert to a state machine and only read characters at the top of your loop.

Comment: @RSahu To be on-topic on Code Review, questions have to contain reasonably correctly working code. Migration to Code Review was rejected because it fails to meet that standard. However, the author would be welcome to post to CR after fixing the obvious bugs first.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really an answer, but it is too long to fit in a comment. IMHO *do not try to mimic `sprintf`*. The standard library version is large, because it is really powerful. If you need to save space, first analyze what you actually need. I think having a set of functions that convert integers (and define what you need : signed/unsigned, size 1, 2 4 or 8 bytes) to string and then concatenate strings could be much lighter, and simpler to write and test.

Do you need to convert pointers, floating points, single chars ? If you answer yes to one of those questions, just implement the converting function (no need for single char : too trivial ...). And if you heavily use them considere writing them in assembly language. But all this is only <del>experience</del> opinion based.

Comment: Your non-answer is the best answer to real problem +1

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the code correct, I'd profile it rather than try to guess which parts are talking the most resources.  (If I *was* guessing, which I'm not, I'd guess division/modulo is a place to look at).